# How do you make multiple radio buttons over an image responsive?

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, responsive

I have a picture of Hawaiian islands and I've placed 8 radio buttons with absolute position. But when I use the Chrome inspector to see if the image with the radio buttons are responsive, I see that they are not and the buttons don't stay on the spot on the image that were on full screen. Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
#radio1{
    position:absolute;
    top:58.9%;
    left:24.4%;
}

#radio2{
    position:absolute;
    top:57.5%;
    left:27.1%;
}

#radio3{
    position:absolute;
    top:63.2%;
    left:34.05%;
}

#radio4{
    position:absolute;
    top:66.8%;
    left:38%;
}

#radio5{
    position:absolute;
    top:68.9%;
    left:40.4%;
}

#radio6{
    position:absolute;
    top:69.7%;
    left:38.8%;
}

#radio7{
    position:absolute;
    top:73.1%;
    left:40.5%;
}

#radio8{
    position:absolute;
    top:78.8%;
    left:45.5%;
}

#third.form img{
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

HTML:

```
<img src="map.png">
<label for="radio1"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" required><br>
<label for="radio2"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"><br>
<label for="radio3"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3"><br>
<label for="radio4"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4"><br>
<label for="radio5"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5"><br>
<label for="radio6"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6"><br>
<label for="radio7"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7"><br>
<label for="radio8"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8"><br>
```

Comment: could you provide your html as well?

Comment: here you go. I added the part with the radio buttons

Comment: is the image width and height fixed?

Comment: I suppose no because I made the image responsive so it can get smaller when the user is using the phone

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the the dots position changes because the left and top positions are with respect to the entire container and not the containing div itself.

Comment: I understand your comment but I don't know how to do it. Should i use margin- left and margin-top instead of top and left or is it the same?

Comment: i dont think margin-left or margin-right would produce any different results. I have one solution. you could set the left/top positions dynamically using javascript when the window is resized. i'm trying to find out whether it can be done by css alone.

Comment: The whole exercise is for my university and we have a restriction in this one to use only css and html so i suppose it can be done but i don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you are positioning the radio buttons absolute to the body element.

Since image tag is inline and cannot hold html child elements, simply place the radio buttons in a div (parent) and add a background image to your div. Then you will notice how the radio button are positioned absolute to the parent (`div` container)

```css
#container{
  position:relative;
  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiWmnVBwnR9ddbHOGmGaoA3gTrU5r3pslI-IybKWIJz4Amy6VA);
  background-size:cover;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
#radio1{
position:absolute;
top:58.9%;
left:24.4%;
}

#radio2{
position:absolute;
top:57.5%;
left:27.1%;
}

#radio3{
 position:absolute;
top:63.2%;
left:34.05%;
}

#radio4{
position:absolute;
top:66.8%;
left:38%;
}

#radio5{
position:absolute;
top:68.9%;
left:40.4%;
}

#radio6{
position:absolute;
top:69.7%;
left:38.8%;
}

#radio7{
position:absolute;
top:73.1%;
left:40.5%;
}

#radio8{
position:absolute;
top:78.8%;
left:45.5%;
}

#third.form img{
display:block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label for="radio1"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" required><br>
  <label for="radio2"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"><br>
  <label for="radio3"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3"><br>
  <label for="radio4"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4"><br>
  <label for="radio5"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5"><br>
  <label for="radio6"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6"><br>
  <label for="radio7"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7"><br>
  <label for="radio8"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use a container to wrap the radio button children, and you can set the island image as the background.

Then make use of the media queries to set the image size to achieve a responsive design.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://hawaiian-words.com/hw/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/hawaii-island-road-map.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 884px;
  height: 927px;
}

#radio1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58.9%;
  left: 24.4%;
}

#radio2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 57.5%;
  left: 27.1%;
}

#radio3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63.2%;
  left: 34.05%;
}

#radio4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66.8%;
  left: 38%;
}

#radio5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68.9%;
  left: 40.4%;
}

#radio6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 69.7%;
  left: 38.8%;
}

#radio7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.1%;
  left: 40.5%;
}

#radio8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78.8%;
  left: 45.5%;
}

#third.form img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 884px;
    height: 927px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 663px;
    height: 695px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 442px;
    height: 463px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="radio1"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" required><br>
  <label for="radio2"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"><br>
  <label for="radio3"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3"><br>
  <label for="radio4"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4"><br>
  <label for="radio5"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5"><br>
  <label for="radio6"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6"><br>
  <label for="radio7"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7"><br>
  <label for="radio8"></label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the code by @repzero which is similar to yours. Thank you though that was the trick (making a new div relative with background picture)